# Pandas + Selenium the numbers in the loop are not increasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium

I am using pandas and selenium. I am comparing the values in the rows in the "BILGILENDIRME - EN" column, if they are equal, I want them to enter the information I keep in the variables into the relevant input.
and I want it to increment by one for each row. but my code is not working.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip as pc
import pandas as pd
import time

information_gathering_compare = 1
scanning_compare = 2
enumeration_compare = 3

information_gathering_en = "test1"
information_gathering_tr = "test2"
scanning_en = "test3"
scanning_tr = "test4"
enumeration_en = "test5"
enumeration_tr = "test6"

df1 = pd.read_excel('aciklama.xlsx')
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
      
      scroll_1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
      stage_name_en = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input[1]')
      stage_tr_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/span[2]').click()
      stage_name_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input[2]')
      b = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
      for bx in b:
          
          xe = df1['BILGILENDIRME - EN'][bx] = bx+1
          if information_gathering_compare == xe:
            pc.copy(information_gathering_en)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/textarea[1]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/label/span[2]').click()
            pc.copy(information_gathering_tr)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/textarea[2]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
          if scanning_compare == xe+1:
            pc.copy(scanning_en)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/textarea[1]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/label/span[2]').click()
            pc.copy(scanning_tr)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/textarea[2]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
          if enumeration_compare == xe+2:
            pc.copy(enumeration_en)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/textarea[1]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/label/span[2]').click()
            pc.copy(enumeration_tr)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/textarea[2]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

What I want to convey in the image.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t5uR.png)

Comment: Will you please provide more of your code? What is `pc`?

Comment: sure, i added...